# How to read a specific line of data from a csv file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a code that can read a specific line of data from a csv file in python.

```
import csv
with open('details.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    selected_details = input("Enter student ID for details:\n")
    for selected_details in reader:
        print(reader)
```

How could I take an input and then use that to select and print that specific row?

Comment: The code you have written defines `selected_details` as a user input, but immediately redefines `selected_details` as a row from the csv file.  See @Rakesh's answer.

Comment: Which column is the student id in?

Comment: @PeterWood Its the first

Comment: You want `for row in reader: if selected_details == row[0]: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filter should do the trick, something like

```
import csv
with open('details.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    selected_details = input("Enter student ID for details:\n")
    results = filter(lambda x: selected_details in x, reader)
    for line in results:
        print(line)
```

### Explanation:

Filter take an itterable (here reader) and will apply for each element of the itterable the lambda you give him and will return a new list "filtered". If the lambda return True the element will be returned in the filtered list.

A lambda is basically a dwarf-function (wiser, nerdier people will correct me on this over simplification but you get the idea) that return the one and only line you gave him.

So my lambda just does the operation "selected_details in x" that will return True if selected_details is in x and else False, you get the idea.

Comment: Yes I got it to work. Could you explain how exactly it works?

Comment: Wouldn't this find any matching column. e.g. the name of the student's teacher, or hometown, etc?

Comment: Technically yes, but I have no idea what the csv look like, with the structure you could limit the filter to only the relevant column. ( "selected_details in x[0]" for example)

Comment: @RaphaelTodo if you have no idea what the csv looks like you should clarify the question before answering it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a default value.

This will return the first row where the `idx` index equals `value` or `None` if it is not found:

```
import csv


def find_by_position(filename, idx, value):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        row = next((item for item in reader if item[idx] == value), None)

    return row
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> # `data/data.csv` looks like this:
... # 
... # id,name,score
... # 1,bla,65
... # 5,another name,95
... # 9,test,95
...
>>> find_by_position('data/data.csv', 0, '5')
['5', 'another name', '95']
>>> find_by_position('data/data.csv', 1, 'bla')
['1', 'bla', '65']
```

A more descriptive approach would be to use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.DictReader) so that we can search based on the column name:

```
import csv


def find_by_column(filename, column, value):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        row = next((item for item in reader if item[column] == value), None)

    return row
```

Usage is very similar to the previous approach:

```
>>> # `data/data.csv` looks like this:
... # 
... # id,name,score
... # 1,bla,65
... # 5,another name,95
... # 9,test,95
...
>>> find_by_column('data/data.csv', 'id', '5')
OrderedDict([('id', '5'), ('name', 'another name'), ('score', '95')])
>>> find_by_column('data/data.csv', 'name', 'bla')
OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('name', 'bla'), ('score', '65')])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over each line and check if the user inputted data is in line.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

selected_details = input("Enter student ID for details:\n")
with open('details.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        if selected_details in line:
            print(reader)
            break
```

Comment: What if the student id also happens to be in another column. e.g. `id=1`, `siblings=1`